# MongoDB SocketException: : Connection reset

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-timeout, socket-timeout-exception

I have a spring boot applicaiton running which connects to mongoserver in azure cloud.
The app continuesly gets `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` exception for the first request after 4 secs idletime and fail.
Then the subsequent requests are processed after a new connection is established.

Mongo client configuration

```
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final String address = serverAddress;
        
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, database, primaryPassword.toCharArray());
        ServerAddress sAddress = new ServerAddress(address, port);

        MongoClientOptions.Builder opBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        opBuilder.sslEnabled(true);
        opBuilder.requiredReplicaSetName(requiredReplicaSetName);
        opBuilder.maxConnectionIdleTime(1500000);
        opBuilder.socketTimeout(30000);
        opBuilder.connectTimeout(30000);

        // MongoClient
        return new MongoClient(sAddress, credential, opBuilder.build());
    }
```

and the exception:

```
    2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception sending message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$1(AbstractMongoQuery.java:115) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.14.RELEASE]
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at 
        ... 98 common frames omitted
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:525) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 130 common frames omitted
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
       2020-08-05T11:40:55.34-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 152 common frames omitted
```

I tried changing the connection timeout, socketimeout and maxConnectionIdleTime to increase/decrese but the app continuesly gets this exception after 4sec of idle time.

Comment: I think you need to decrease keepalive interval in your system tcp settings.

Comment: To something like 100 seconds.

Comment: SPring boot app is running in PCF cloud. How do I set it and could you explain the reason you believe that is causing the issue

Comment: I suggest you research that on your own.